# Why is the function being seen as a global variable

Tags: python, tkinter

The error that I am receiving is: Global name 'OnButtonClick2' is not defined. I am not sure if the program is reading the function as a variable instead of as a function, and I don't know what I should do to fix it. I pass through both the parameters so I'm confused as to why it will not work.

```
import Tkinter

def convertDtoB(binary,left):                  
    if(left>0):                                 
        binary+=str(left%2)                     
        return convertDtoB(binary,left//2)      
    else:
        binary = int(binary[::-1])            
        return binary

def convertBtoD(decimal):                    
    answer = 0                                  
    length = len(str(decimal))                  
    decimal2 = str(decimal)[::-1]               
    for i in range(length):
        answer+=int(decimal2[i])*2**i
    return answer

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)

        self.button1 = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Convert Decimal to Binary", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick(1))
        self.button1.grid(column=1,row=1)

        self.button2 = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Convert Binary to Decimal", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick(2))
        self.button2.grid(column=1,row=2)

        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable, anchor="center", bg="white")
        label.grid(column=1,row=0,columnspan=2,sticky='')
        self.labelVariable.set("Select a conversion.")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())

    def OnButtonClick2(self, button_id):
        if button_id == 3:
            binaryNumber = convertDtoB("",self.decimalNumber)
            self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
            label_2 = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable, anchor="center", bg="white")
            label_2.grid(column=1,row=0,columnspan=2,sticky='')
            self.label_2.set(binaryNumber)
        elif button_id == 4:
            binaryNumber = convertBtoD("",self.binaryNumber)
            self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
            label_2 = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable, anchor="center", bg="white")
            label_2.grid(column=1,row=0,columnspan=2,sticky='')
            self.label_2.set(binaryNumber)

    def OnButtonClick(self, button_id):
        if button_id == 1:
            self.button1.destroy()
            self.button2.destroy()
            self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
            self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
            self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW')
            self.decimalNumber = self.entryVariable.set("Enter Decimal Number Here")
            self.entry.focus_set()
            self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

            button3 = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Click here to convert", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick(3))
            button3.grid(column=1,row=1)

            self.OnButtonClick2(3)

        elif button_id == 2:
            self.button1.destroy()
            self.button2.destroy()
            self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
            self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
            self.entry.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='EW')
            self.binaryNumber = self.entryVariable.set("Enter Binary Number Here.")
            self.entry.focus_set()
            self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

            button4 = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Click here to convert", command=lambda: self.OnButtonClick(4))
            button4.grid(column=1,row=1)

            self.OnButtonClick2(4)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you post the traceback in full?

Comment: I think it might be confusing for future viewers of this question that you have fixed the code in your post.. Just an observation

Comment: I will switch it back, I just wanted you guys to be able to see the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `self` is most likely incorrect if these functions are being defined *inside a class*, and are therefore *methods/member functions* of that class. If this is the case:

You should be calling the method like so:

```
self.OnButtonClick2(3)
```

Assuming these functions are methods being defined inside a class(otherwise your use of `self` is incorrect), then this is correct way to call a defined method within it's own class.

**Info on classes [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)**

Comment: Actually, since __self__ is just a convention, your opening statement is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By your use of `self` I assume you are inside a class. To call other class methods you want to use:

```
self.OnButtonClick2(3)
```

Comment: I did this and was able to fix the problem right away, but it lead me to realize I have a few more problems, mainly which are related to the binaryNumber and decimalNumber variables. There is also an error with the first parameter when I run my convertDtoB function and convertBtoD function. ("",decimalNumber) is the parameter, and the error is with the "" of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few syntax issues with the code in the question.

- No leading 'def' keyword for function/methods
- no indentation on line after the func/method declaration.

Are these functions... or methods in a class? I ask because the first params are 'self'. Leads me to believe these are methods in a class. In which case to call a method you'd do:

```
self.OnButtonClick2(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`OnButtonClick2` is defined as a method of a class:

```
class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    ...
    def OnButtonClick2(self, button_id):
```

When you do this, you must call this function by prefixing it with the instance of an object based on this class. For example, to call it from outside the class you would do something like this:

```
app = simpleapp_tk()
...
app.OnButtonClick2(...)
```

If you want to call or refer to this function from within the class, the code must refer to itself which, by convention, is `self`. Thus, to call the function from within the class you would do:

```
self.OnButtonClick(...)
```

In the original version of your question, there was one place in your code where you were omitting the `self.` part:

```
OnButtonClick2(self,3)
```

Since `OnButtonCllick2` only lives inside the class, and because you didn't tell python which instance of the class you want to  use to call this function, python assumes you are trying to call a global function. Since no global function exists with that name, it gives the error that you report.

The solution should be clear: when you call `OnButtonClick`, always use `self.OnButtonClick` when calling from inside the class.